# HTML for is not being submitted after clicking on the submit button

Tags: php, html, forms, submit

I have the following form:

```
<form method="post">
    <div class="control-group form-group">
        <div class="controls">
            <label class="contact-p1">Full Name:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name.">
            <p class="help-block"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group form-group">
        <div class="controls">
            <label class="contact-p1">Email Address:</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address.">
            <p class="help-block"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group form-group">
        <div class="controls">
            <label class="contact-p1">Description</label>
            <textarea placeholder="Your text here.." name="description" class="form-control" rows="8" required></textarea>
            <p class="help-block"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="success"></div>
    <!-- For success/fail messages -->
    <input type="submit" value="Send" name="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block btn-lg">
</form>
```

And in the same file below the form, I have the following php form statement where I check if the form is submitted or not:

```
 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
     echo "<h1>" . "Form is submitted" . "</h1>";
 } else {
     echo "<h1>" . "Form is not submitted" . "</h1>";
 }
```

After clicking the "Send" button I cannot enter the "Form is submitted" `if`. I'm not sure why?

Comment: When you first load that file you should see **Form is not submitted** do u see it? if not what do u see?

Comment: Yes, the first load is "Form is not submitted" after clicking the button the page is not refreshed

Comment: Your code contains id's and this to me, suggests you're probably using JS for it. What you posted works. How are you using this also? as a server url or directly in your browser as `file:///`? if the former, check for errors with error reporting. I can't see this failing here.

Comment: *"after clicking the button the page is not refreshed"* - Refreshed? I don't see any redirection here.

Comment: I just used that code as it is and it works... if the form is not refreshed after submit then you are  not showing us all your code

Comment: ^ I agree with the above.

Comment: Do you use `.preventDefault()` on form submission anywhere in your js code?

Comment: Please delete this question.

Comment: You are using jqBootstrapValidation plugin this is perhaps why it supresses posting, probably you prevent submitting in code as explained here https://reactiveraven.github.io/jqBootstrapValidation/#configuration_options_preventsubmit

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile [there you go............](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47054911/html-for-is-not-being-submitted-after-clicking-on-the-submit-button#comment81057116_47055140).

Comment: your question did not contain relevant code. I told you earlier about my suspecting your use of JS and you're probably doing this for self-rep. The question is marked for unclearness. This will not serve anyone on Stack except **yourself**. That isn't what Stack is about, not just "you you you", there are others here you know.

Answer (score -2):

This should work, the naming of the submit button wasn't working.

```
<?php

     if (isset($_POST['SubmitForm'])) {
             echo "<h1>" . "Form is submitted" . "</h1>";
          } else {
             echo "<h1>" . "Form is not submitted" . "</h1>";
     }

     ?>

    <form method="post">
                        <div class="control-group form-group">
                            <div class="controls">
                                <label class="contact-p1">Full Name:</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name.">
                                <p class="help-block"></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="control-group form-group">
                            <div class="controls">
                                <label class="contact-p1">Email Address:</label>
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address.">
                                <p class="help-block"></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="control-group form-group">
                            <div class="controls">
                                <label class="contact-p1">Description</label>
                                    <textarea placeholder="Your text here.." name="description" class="form-control" rows="8" required></textarea>
                                <p class="help-block"></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="success"></div>
                        <!-- For success/fail messages -->
                        <input type="submit" value="Send" name="SubmitForm" class="btn btn-success btn-block btn-lg">
     </form>
```

Answer (score -2):

The problem was in the JavaScript file for the contact form. After removing this:

```
event.preventDefault(); // prevent default submit behaviour
```

The form is now working. Thanks all for the help :)

Comment: [See, I was right...........](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47054911/html-for-is-not-being-submitted-after-clicking-on-the-submit-button#comment81056884_47054911). JS.

Comment: Thought as much @Fred-ii-

Comment: Thanks Fred, have a nice day

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile Yep!

Comment: I think the purpose was to gain rep @Fred-ii-

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile I think so also.